# What's the "events" supported by Ajax Facelets?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

### What's the possible values for "events" in Ajax Facelets tag?

I was thinking about what's the possible values for "event" attribute inside Ajax Facelets tag. I'm using JSF 2.0 and when I go to [Facelets documentation](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) I can't find this information.

I just know `keyup` and `keydown` values:

```
<f:ajax event="keyup"/>
<f:ajax event="keydown"/>
```

**What's the full list of values that can be used inside the `facelets` tags?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exact link you provided us with:

> If specified, it must be **one of the events supported by the component**
>   the Ajax behavior is being applied to. For HTML components this would
>   be the set of **supported DOM events** for the component, plus "action"
>   for Faces ActionSource components and "valueChange" for Faces
>   EditableValueHolder components. If not specified, the default event is
>   determined for the component. The DOM event name is the actual DOM
>   event name (for example: "click") as opposed to (for example:
>   "onclick").

What do you need more than this?

See also:

- [ClientBehaviorHolder#getEventNames](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html#getEventNames%28%29) : defines events a UIComponent implementation supports. [HtmlInputText](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.html) for example defines this events list, meaning you can `<f:ajax event` any of these:

```java
private static final Collection<String> EVENT_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList("blur","change","valueChange","click","dblclick","focus","keydown","keypress","keyup","mousedown","mousemove","mouseout","mouseover","mouseup","select"))
```